# How to customize nonlinear constraints?

Tags: drake

I am trying to design some nonlinear constraints in my project. In previous version, I utilized the abstract class drake::solvers::NonLinearConstraint to derive my nonlinear constraint. I doesn't find this class in current vesion, even the header file drake/solvers/nonlinear_constraint.h. How can i design nonlinear constraints within current version?

I try to seacrch in C++ documentation with the keywords **nonlinear** and **nonlinear constraint**, but it doesn't help. Any substitute api and example for this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just want to use `drake::solvers::Constraint`. You can find  many examples in the codebase, e.g. the [`ComPositionConstraint`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/b081fce2af3871b5c2e8cc9c860774435bf41cf1/multibody/inverse_kinematics/com_position_constraint.h#L20).

```
class ComPositionConstraint final : public solvers::Constraint {
```